# boost::bind with Ros Service

Tags: ros, c++, boost

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a ROS Service GripperState

```
---
int32 gripperState
int32 paddleState
```

And In my main.cpp file I have this line since I need gripper data from robot needs to be passed to service

```
ros::ServiceServer gripperService = 
    n.advertiseService<my_robot::GripperState::Request, my_robot::GripperState::Response>
    ("GripperState",boost::bind(&gripperControl, node->getGripper(), 
    (my_robot::GripperState::Request &) _2,  (my_robot::GripperState::Response &) _3));
```

In GripperServer.cpp I have the definition of method gripperControl

```
bool gripperControl(ArGripper *gripper, my_robot::GripperState::Request &req, my_robot::GripperState::Response &res)
{
    int32_t gSt = gripper->getGripState();
    int32_t pSt = gripper->getPaddleState();
    ROS_INFO("GripperSt : %d, PaddleSt: %d", gSt, pSt);
    res.gripperState = 5;
    res.paddleState = 10;
    return true;
}
```

However it compiles. It doesn't work since boost doesn't pass the placeholders _2 and _3 as references.(I think it creates a copy of each parameter).

Is there any way to make this work?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214513/boost::bind-with-ros-service/) by [Ongun Kanat](https://answers.ros.org/users/23342/ongun-kanat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-07-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First of all, I don't think those casts (  `(my_robot::GripperState::Request &)` ) before the `_2` and `_3` are necessary.

But, most importantly, I think you're numbering your arguments incorrectly. `_2` should be `_1` and  `_3` should be `_2`. Those underscored arguments refer to the args passed to the boost functor returned by `boost::bind`; so having 2 and 3 implies that it's receiving 3 arguments and it should ignore the first. When, in reality,  ROS only passes it two arguments (the request and the response).

---

Originally posted by [Benjamin Blumer](https://answers.ros.org/users/3673/benjamin-blumer/) with karma: 287 on 2015-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1